# Why doesn't this Jackson pretty print function work?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Why doesn't this Jackson pretty print function work?   Just trying to read a file and pretty print it using jackson api:

```
public static void printJsonFromFile( String fileName ) {
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        System.out.println( mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
           .writeValueAsString( readFile( fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 )) );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------");
}
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException 
{
     byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get( path ) );
     return encoding.decode( ByteBuffer.wrap( encoded ) ).toString();
}
```

Comment: In this case, I don't think it has anything to serialize and pretty print it, as the the input object itself is a String. If you de-serialize it in readFile(..), it may pretty print the JSON for the input object.

Comment: Ok, so if I deserialize into a JsonNode with ObjectMapper, then I should be able to pretty print it right?  Not completely sure how I would do that thought.  I'll research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your `System.out` call with the following:

```
Object json = mapper.readValue(readFile(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Object.class);
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json));
```

This should properly indent your json.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It sounds like your saying that I can use "Object.class" as a "dummy class" for the deserialization?

Comment: Exactly - the intermediary `Object` will mean you don't have to roll a specific entity to bind your json to. Then, you re-serialize the `Object`.

Comment: That works; you can also use `ObjectMapper.readTree()` method to get a `JsonNode`. Not much difference, both build a simple representation in memory, serialize it.