# Jackson pretty print string

Tags: java, json, jackson

At some places we are logging JSON strings. For better readability we want to pretty print them. Therefore we are using:

```
v_JsonString = v_ObjectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(v_Json);
```

But after passing the result to the logger the string is only single line, the line breaks etc are gone. The used logging pattern is:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
```

We also tried to do it manually by setting some placeholders and replace them in the pattern:

```
%replace(%msg){'PLACEHOLDER', '\\n'}
```

Without any success, every log entry is converted to single line. What is the correct way to preserve formatted string information?

**EDIT**
The problem is not the logger, Jackson does not pretty print strings without serialization, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39119883/1924298

Comment: Did you check the resulting (prettyprinted) string for actually containing newlines?

Comment: Shame on me, as I did not check the writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter result. The debugger shows no line breaks.

Comment: Sometimes I feel bad asking for these things. People get offended sometimes. But as you see: Always double check ...

Answer (score 3):

```
Object json = mapper.readValue(input, Object.class);

String indented = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. The problem was not the logger / settings. The real cause is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871355/1924298

**EDIT**

The problem is not solved as getting serialization error when trying with type "Object". I will edit the original question.